# Unload plupload from a div

Tags: jquery, plupload

I'm using plupload with

```
$("#plupload_div").pluploadQueue({
        // General settings
        runtimes : 'flash,html5',
        url : '/products/save_photo',
        max_file_size : '10mb',
        //chunk_size : '1mb',
        unique_names : true,   
        resize : {width : 558, height : 418, quality : 90},     
        multipart: true,        
        multipart_params : {"photo[variant_id]" : variant_id, authenticity_token : atoken},        
        filters : [ {title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,gif,png"}],        
        flash_swf_url : '/javascripts/plupload.flash.swf',        
      });
```

What i have to do to unload plupload from element  #plupload_div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#plupload_div').unbind();
```

does this help?

calling unbind() without args removes all handlers attached to the elements

Comment: It's OK! But it is not enough if using Flash Runtime. You need to remove DIV to make sure object was deleted from DOM. If we try to call plupload again, IE trows error at line 49 in Flash in function __add__callback because object remains on page. @jayarjo answer is the better approach because removes plupload object from page, so we can add it again latter.

Answer (score 11):

You can do it as follows:

```
var uploader = $("#plupload_div").pluploadQueue(); 
uploader.destroy();
$("#plupload_div").remove();
```

This will unbind all the events and remove Plupload structure from the page.

Alternatively you might want to check [Plupload UI Widget](http://www.plupload.com/example_jquery_ui.php) - another implementation of the Plupload Core API, which is skinnable (uses jQuery UI Themes), more flexible overall (has similar to UI widgets method and event model) and has public destroy method, that can be called like this:

```
$("#plupload_div").plupload('destroy');
```

Comment: $("#plupload_div").plupload('destroy'); doesn't work for me with Plupload UI widget. I still have to use uploader.destroy();

Comment: How I did it :     `uploaded: function(event, args) {
        $("#uploader").plupload('destroy'); 
        $('#uploader').remove();
    }`

Answer (score 1):

uploader.destroy(); is enough to handle it

Comment: I was having problems with an element being bound multiple time and this worked for me.